# Copying Multiple Ranges VBA in Email Body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

my goal is to create a macro that will copy a multiple or ranges in the body of an email.
Which range will be pasted will depend on if the cell associated with specific range is equal to True.

For example, if cell S11 is equal to True then range("BO2:O5") should be one of the range pasted.
Or if both cell S11 and S13 are equal to true, then the range("BO2:O5") and range("BO6:O10") should be pasted one above the other.

The problem I'm encountering is if for example cell S15 is equal to True, my Macro will also paste all the previous ranges even if their value in the S column was False.

For example:

```
 S11 = True ->range("B2:O5")
 S12 = False ->range("B6:O10")
 S13 = False ->range("B11:O15")
 S14 = False ->range("B16:O20")
 S15 = True ->range("B21:O25")
 S16 = False ->range("B26:O30")
```

I would normally only want ranges ("B2:O5") and ("B21:O25") to be pasted, but my problem is all ranges prior to S15 will also be included.

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim X
    Dim concatenatedRange As Range
    Dim rangeArray As Variant
    
    dt = Date
    
    ' Create an array of ranges to check
    rangeArray = Array( _
        Sheets("Price Table").Range("B2:O5"), _
        Sheets("Price Table").Range("B6:O9"), _
        Sheets("Price Table").Range("B10:O35"), _
        Sheets("Price Table").Range("B36:O63"), _
        Sheets("Price Table").Range("B64:O93"), _
        Sheets("Price Table").Range("B94:O125"), _
        Sheets("Price Table").Range("B126:O148") _
    )
    
    ' Loop through the ranges and concatenate if the corresponding cell in column S is TRUE
    For i = 11 To 17
        If Range("S" & i).Value = True Then
            If concatenatedRange Is Nothing Then
                Set concatenatedRange = rangeArray(i - 11)
            Else
                Set concatenatedRange = Union(concatenatedRange, rangeArray(i - 11))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Create Outlook email
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .Body = "Good Morning , " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please find below the Agricultural Market report for " & dt & " below. If you would like to see some quotations, please do let us know." & vbCrLf
        
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        ' Copy the concatenated range if it exists
        If Not concatenatedRange Is Nothing Then
            X = doc.Range.End - 1
            concatenatedRange.Copy
            doc.Range(X).Paste
        End If
        
        .To = "****@****.com;****@****.com"
        .CC = "****@***.com"
        .Subject = "Ags Market Update " & dt
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
        
        .Display 'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
    End With
End Sub
```

If you could please suggest any solutions to my problem that'd be much appreciated! Cheers

Comment: Are you sure S12 really evaluates to `false` - check this while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

- If `concatenatedRange` is a non-contiguous range object, for example, `Range("B2:O5, B21:O25")`, copying and pasting it in Excel yields a desirable result. The two areas (B2:O5, B21:O25) are positioned next to each other.
- However, when pasting it in other Office applications, such as `Word`, the output will be `B2:O25`. That is `Range("B2:O5", "B21:O25")`.
- Please try to loop through each area of a non-contiguous range object

```vb
        If Not concatenatedRange Is Nothing Then
            Dim rArea As Range
            For Each rArea In concatenatedRange.Areas
                X = doc.Range.End - 1
                rArea.Copy
                doc.Range(X).Paste
            Next
        End If
```